# Using probability in python

Tags: python

Let's say i have a 2D array named `grid` of size `(N,N)`.The `NxN` array cells can either be 0 or 1.First i initialise all the array cells as 0.Then what i would like to do is iterate through the array and change 0's to 1's with  given probability p.What i mean is this:

```
p=0.5
for i in range(0,N-1)
  for j in range(0,N-1) //iteration through every cell
    // grid[i][j] has p=50% chance to change from 0 to 1
```

How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters, and you don't mind a dependency on SciPy, there's

```py
import scipy.stats as st
grid = st.bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=(N, N))
```

or NumPy's

```py
import numpy as np
grid = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, size=(N, N))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying a solution here. 
Sample from 0-1 , according to the dimensions you want. 
Then according to p, converting those > p to 1 and < p to 0 will be what you need

```
import numpy as np
p=0.3
N=5
(np.random.random_sample((N, N)) > p).astype(int)
```